# Elementary equivalence of ordinals as ordered sets

Tags: first-order-logic, model-theory

I am trying to solve this problem:

> Show that $\aleph_1$ and $\omega$ are not elementarily equivalent as ordered sets (here $\aleph_1$ denotes the first uncountable cardinal)
>
> Show there exists some countable ordinal that is an elementary substructure of $\aleph_1$.

I am working in the language $\{<\}$. For the first part I think I just need a sentence that is true in $\omega$ and false in $\aleph_1$ but I am having trouble coming up with a difference between the two that is first order expressible- I know how to express "infinite cardinality" but not the distinction between countably and uncountably infinite.

For the second part, if such an ordinal $\alpha$ exists it must be an initial segment of $\aleph_1$. But I don't see how it can be an elementary substructure, since it would have the same cardinality as $\omega$. So if $\omega$ is not elementarily equivalent to $\aleph_1$ because they have different infinite cardinalities, the sentence that is true in $\omega$ and false in $\aleph_1$ must also be true in $\alpha$ so it could not be an elementary substructure?

Comment: For the second part, modify the proof of the (downward) Löwenheim-Skolem theorem to produce an initial segment.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Can't you just exhibit a countable ordinal which is elementarily equivalent to $\omega_1$? I'm guessing that $\omega^\omega$ will do the trick.

Comment: @bof a priori it's not immediately clear that that ordinal will be an _elementary substructure_ of $\aleph_1$. in general you can have substructures that are elementary equivalent but not elementary substructures; consider for example $2\mathbb{Z}$ as a substructure of $(\mathbb{Z},<)$

Answer (score 2):

For (1), let $P(x) = \neg \exists y (y < x \land \forall z (z < x \to z = y \lor z < y)$. This is the statement that something is not a successor ordinal. Then $\omega$ satisfies $\exists ! x P(x)$, while $\aleph_1$ does not.

For (2), using downward Lowenheim-Skolem, construct a sequence of countable ordinals $\{a_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ such that $a_0$ has an elementary embedding into $\aleph_1$ and, for all $n$, we have $a_n \subseteq a_{n + 1}$, and there is an elementary embedding $a_{n + 1} \to \aleph_1$ which fixes $a_n$. Then $\bigcup\limits_{n \in \mathbb{N}} a_n$ is a countable ordinal. Use the Tarski-Vaught test to show it is an elementary substructure of $\aleph_1$.

Comment: hi Mark, +1, but I think I'm missing something in point 2. that argument certainly shows there is a countable ordinal elementarily equivalent to $\aleph_1$, but how do you know that it will actually be an elementary _substructure_ of $\aleph_1$?

Comment: @AtticusStonestrom You are indeed correct. I suspect there is some way to show it will be, but I sidestepped the issue in my edited proof.

Comment: An easier idea for (2) is to build a sequence of countable substructures of $\aleph_1$, alternating closing under Skolem functions and closing downward in $\aleph_1$. The union is a downwards-closed elementary substructure of $\aleph_1$.

Comment: @MarkSaving I'd recommend to edit your answer according to Alex suggestion!